# Using Rails' view helpers inside javascript templates

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, template-engine, form-helpers, eco

I'd like to be able to use some of rails' view and form helpers, such as `<%= image_tag .. %>` or `<%= select_tag .. %>` inside my javascript templates. I read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8317266/187907) that suggested pre-rendering the erb as a string in some javascript variable and then calling it from the template (it'll have to be available before the js template is called). So I could do something like this:

#### view_helpers.js.erb

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var ViewHelpers = {
      CountrySelect: "<%= select_tag "person[country_id]", options_from_collection_for_select(Country.all, "name", "id"), :prompt => '-Country-' %>"
  };
</script>
```

And then call it from my eco template (rendered later):

#### edit_person.jst.eco

```
...
<p>
  <label for="person_country_id">Country</label>
  <%= ViewHelpers.CountrySelect %>
</p>
...
```

However, I seem to be unable to load it both as part of the view or using the asset pipeline:

#### Asset Pipeline: application.js

(saved in app/assets/javascripts/views/people/view_helpers.js.erb)

```
//= require ./views/people/view_helpers
```

### OR

#### ERB template: views/people/index.html.erb

(saved in app/views/people/view_helpers.js.erb)

```
<%= render :template => 'people/view_helpers' %>
```

Am I approaching this problem completely wrong or have I missed something? thanks.

Comment: Have you read this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7451517/using-a-rails-helper-method-within-a-javascript-asset I think there's some useful information regarding your problem.

Comment: No, missed that one, and it seemed to do the trick - I was missing an include to `ActionView::Helpers`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. You can even use it with partials:

update_js.js.erb:

```
$('#element').html('<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => @partial, :locals => {:my_var => @item })) %>');
```

in controller you should have format `js`:

```
   respond_to do |format|
      format.js do
        render :update_js do |page|
          page.replace_html "element", :partial => @partial
        end
      end
    end
```

if you want to call this js with AJAX simply pass `:remote => true` to your link

```
<%= link_to 'replace content', item_path(@item), :remote => true %>
```