# Rails ejs undefined method

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, backbone.js

I'm following this question: [Rails with backbone-rails: asset helpers (image_path) in EJS files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8316814/rails-with-backbone-rails-asset-helpers-image-path-in-ejs-files).

I have my .jst.ejs.erb files in app/assets/javascripts/templates.

My code in a template looks like:

```
<li><%= link_to "Sign In", new_user_session_path %> </li>
```

But I'm getting the error:

```
undefined local variable or method `new_user_session'
```

even though my rake routes command shows there is definitely a route there.

I have a ejs.rb initalizer that looks like:

```
EJS.evaluation_pattern    = /\{\{([\s\S]+?)\}\}/
EJS.interpolation_pattern = /\{\{=([\s\S]+?)\}\}/
```

If I try what the second answer suggests, there aren't any errors on the page, but it shows "False" where the link should go.

Answer (score 1):

i guess this will work

```
<li><%= link_to "Sign In", new_user_session_path %> </li>
```

Comment: Oops, forgot to change that back when I was trying to fix the problem. But it still doesn't fix it?